# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Collapse in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

So, I am building a site for a client and have encountered this odd problem. I am using Bootstrap to build in the responsiveness and using Wordpress to manage the content. Everything is working fine except for one issue I ran into that I cannot find a solution for.

I have a nabber that collapses at the smaller viewport sizes and a toggle switch that changes from a hamburger to an "X" when clicked. The menu behaves fine on open, sliding in from the left and covering all the content. But when I click on the close button the menu slide back out to the left, but then will receive the "show" class and immediately open again.

I built a Codepen that uses the same HTML and CSS as the Wordpress site, but stripped to the bare bones. It works fine. So I am thinking there is something about Wordpress that is interfering and adding that "show" class after the menu closes.

https://codepen.io/j_lyman/pen/EbGPPB/

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg bg-white justify-content-between">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation" aria-controls="main-navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            <span class="close hidden">X</span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img src="http://jlr-wp.lymannuthouse.com/wp-content/themes/jlr_twentyeighteen/img/JLR_logo@2x.png" class="logo">
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li id="menu-home" class="nav-item current-menu-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li id="menu-program" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="program.html">Program</a></li>
                <li id="menu-portfolio" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li id="menu-newsroom" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="news.html">Newsroom</a></li>
                <li id="menu-blog" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

My Less is:

```
header {
margin-bottom: 0;
max-height: 81px;

.logo-container {
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;

    img {
        width: 120px;
    }
}
.logo {
    //border: 1px solid red;
}
}

/* --------------- MAIN NAVIGATION ---------------*/
.navbar {
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;

.navbar-toggler {
    border: none;

    .navbar-toggler-icon {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='#FF6600' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;

    }
}

.navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: -5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    //background: @white;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;

    li {
        padding: 0 2rem;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        border-left: 1px solid @ltGray;

        a {
            padding: 2rem 0;
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 15px;
            border-bottom: none;
        }
        &.current-menu-item {
            a {
                font-family: 'Proxima Nova Bold', sans-serif;
                box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 @secondary;
            }
        }
        &:first-child {
            border-left: none;
        }
    }
}
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar {
    .navbar-collapse {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: @dkGray;

        .nav-item {
            border-left: none;
            .nav-link {
                font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light Thin', sans-serif;
                color: @white;
            }
            &.current-menu-item {
                background: lighten(@dkGray, 10%);
                .nav-link {
                    box-shadow: none;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        &:focus {
            outline: none;
        }
        .close {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: @secondary;
        }
        &.collapsed {
            display: inline;

            .close {
                display: none;
            }
        }
        &:not(.collapsed) {
            .close {
                display: inline;
            }
            .navbar-toggler-icon {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease;
    transition: left 0.3s ease;
    left: -100%;
}
.navbar-collapse.show {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
}
}
```

My WP site is located in this temporary location:

https://jlr-wp.lymannuthouse.com

If anyone has seen this behavior before I would appreciate any help as I couldn't find anything online that addressed this particular issue.

Comment: The CodePen seems to be working fine, but the temporary site is unavailable now. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I have not been able to solve it yet. Apparently my hosting provider has some settings that is preventing the site from being seen by everyone. I'm trying to resolve that issue right now. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently there are some settings my client has on their private network that also give them an unavailable or bring up 5** errors. For the most part it hasn't been awful, just inconvenient. Is there anyone who can see the page who can offer a suggestion?

Comment: Now I could have a look. I think the problem is javascript based and a possible cause could be that many of the scripts are loaded multiple times in your page. E.g. `bootstrap.js` and the file at `/wp-content/themes/jlr_twentyeighteen/js/scripts.js`. Try to eliminate this and let's see then.

Comment: That's what it is. I still had my template javascript calls in my Wordpress theme. So it was ending up calling things twice. Seems to be working locally. I'll be uploading this to the server next.

Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: Great, happy to help